# Group items of two in one array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to push numbers in an array into another array in groups of two.

If I have an array `[1,4,3,2];` it should return `[[1,4],[3,2]];`

```js
var arrayPairSum = function(nums) {

    var len = nums.length / 2;
    var arr = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < len; i ++) {
        var newArr = [];
        newArr.push(nums[i]);
        newArr.push(nums[i + 1]);
        arr.push(newArr);
    }

   console.log(arr); //this should give me [[1,4],[3,2]];
};


arrayPairSum([1,4,3,2]);
```

can anyone see what I need to do to achieve this? I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` method to achieve this. `reduce` method accepts a `callback` method provided on every item in the array.

In the other words, this method applies a **function** against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to **reduce** it to a single value.

```js
var array=[1,4,3,2,8];
var contor=array.reduce(function(contor,item,i){
  if(i%2==0)
      contor.push([array[i],array[i+1]].filter(Boolean));
  return contor;
},[]);
console.log(contor);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to iterate over the array, may skip every second index, so `i+=2` ( as satpal already pointed out) :

```js
var arrayPairSum = function(nums) {

  var len = nums.length - 1;//if nums.length is not even, it would crash as youre doing nums[i+1], so thats why -1
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
    var newArr = [];
    newArr.push(nums[i]);
    newArr.push(nums[i + 1]);
    arr.push(newArr);
  }

  console.log(arr); //this should give me [[1,4],[3,2]];
};
arrayPairSum([1, 4, 3, 2]);
```

The upper one crops away every non pair at the end. If you want a single [value] at the end, may go with

```
len=nums.length
```

And check later before pushing

```
if(i+1<nums.length) newArr.push(nums[i+1]);
```

Comment: This will handle `[1,4,3,2,5]`

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. Simply change the length to `nums.length` and in the loop increment `i` by 2.

```js
var arrayPairSum = function(nums) {

    var len = nums.length - 1;
    var arr = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < len; i+=2) {
        var newArr = [];
        newArr.push(nums[i]);
        newArr.push(nums[i + 1]);
        arr.push(newArr);
    }

   console.log(arr); //this should give me [[1,4],[3,2]];
};


arrayPairSum([1,4,3,2]);
```